# SQL to find Invalid Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am trying to import some data from Access to SQL server, however, when I run the import, I get this error

```
Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid date format".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

I like to try and to resolve this by using a script so I don't need to correct all fields by hand - the question is, is there any SQL that can do this?

OK the error is clear, but is still vague if you get me...As in, are the dates that are wrong empty? just in the wrong format? Just corrupted? all of these things?

I hope you understand where I am coming from...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a big vague.  My advice is to load the data into a staging table in SQL Server.  In this table, all the columns would be strings that are long enough to hold the values.

Then, you can investigate the staging table to find the problems.  For instance, you can run:

```
select date
from stagingtable
where isdate(date) = 0 and date is not null;
```

After you figure out the problem, you can load into the final table using something like:

```
insert into finaltable(col1, . . . , coln)
    select col1,
           (case when col2 <> 'N/A' then cast(col2 as date) end) as col2,
           . . .
    from stagingtable;
```